# Расположить изображение поверх фона

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Имеется следующий код:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="content row">
      <div class="col-1"></div>
      <div class="col-10">
        <div class="content-img" >
      </div>
      <div class="col-1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

В CSS задано свойство background-color для content

```
/* Content  */
.content {
    min-height: 1100px;
    background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245);

}

.content-img {
    margin-top: 100px;
    background-image: url(/images/content.jpg);
    width: 1200px;
    height: 900px;
}
```

Как расположить изображение поверх уже заданного фона в content, при этом чтобы картинка находилась в блоке div.

Ниже показано что фон из content накладывается на блок content-img, для этого добавил в content opacity.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Спасибо.

Comment: `z-index`-ы пробовали?

Comment: Да. Пробовал этот вариант.

Comment: Пожалуйста опубликуйте тут в Code Snippet ваш минимальный запускаемый вариант, вместо картинок и кусков кода, так нам всем будет легче отладить ваш код. Возможно проблема кроется в неопубликованных частях кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете попробовать так, но опять таки, пока вы не опубликуете что у вас было я не смогу точно сказать почему у вас это не работает:

```css
.content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: red;
}

.col-10 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.content-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552519507-da3b142c6e3d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OXx8Y2Fyc3xlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="content row">
    <div class="col-1"></div>
    <div class="col-10">
      <div class="content-img">
      </div>
      <div class="col-1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если conent-img уже внутри content, то картинка уже поверх фона. Проверьте, возможно ваша картинка не подгружается. Лучше покажите результат

Comment: Выходит что фон из content накладывается на блок  <div class="content-img" >, в котором фоном установлено изображение. Для наглядности добавил opacity для content чтобы показать что он поверх <div class="content-img" >.

Answer (score 0):

Временное решение выглядит так

```
<div class="content row" style="background-color: black;">
```

СSS

```
.content {
    min-height: 1100px;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).